# Informatics system to go with for implementing an online optical lens ordering form

Tags: magento, attributes

I am working on the development a new optical lens ordering online platform.
Here is the tricky thing. After the user having selected a product (lens type), he will get through a ordering grid platform where he could type quantities he wants for specific lens configurations.

### Grid ordering form for a specific lens type

[image: Grid ordering form for a specific lens type]

There is two parameters to consider: Sphere and Cylinder.

I have already worked on an Optical E-commerce website using Magento Platform. Given my current project is not based on a E-Commerce oriented model, it seems inappropriate to work on this project with this platform. If I set "Sphere" and "Cylinder" as Magento attributes, there would be multiple combinations (more than 200) of configurable products for one lens type.

Despite that, is there a way to go with Magento? If Magento is definitely not the solution, what other informatics platform would you recommend?

Comment: So you have found solution for grid quantity ordering and asking for way to have other than creating configurable(individually larger number of products) ?

Comment: Hello K.C.
No I haven't found yet the way to create this kind of ordering grid. I just put this picture as an example of what I would like to get.
About Magento, if I consider a product (lens type) can have heaps of variations based on sphere/cylinder combinations, with sphere and cylinder set up as product attributes, it seems to be complicated to go with this platform. 
Another specific rule I have to consider is that for example the end user is able to order Sphere: -6.00 Cylinder: +2.00 for Lens#1 but this range is not available for Lens #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, The solution you are requiring is called as `product grid`. Please have a look at [this module](http://www.auguria.com/magento/auguria-productmatrix.html) . What i can guarantee with this module is you can achieve the quantity input in grid. (It creates taking configurable options of products.)

As you have said **..end user is able to order Sphere: -6.00 Cylinder: +2.00 for Lens#1 but this range is not available..** You won't have to worry about this, if you aren't creating product with this range then, the quantity input field won't appear within that grid.

Comment: Thanks K.C.
This module you've shared could be a solution but the thing is I will get a line per combination that means 200 lines in average for each product view. It is more convenient for end user to have the kind of ordering grid like in the picture I shared. I know that Magento is a powerful tool in wide range of functionalities but I am wondering if it's a good choice regarding the view I have to build in frontend. Plus, I would like the products to be selected in a drop-down list instead of the built-in Magento views. The specific grid would be displayed after each selection.

Comment: @Jukemax So you want to select from drop-down rather than this grid for various combinations?

Comment: Thank you very much. The Auguria extension is perfect for my need. I just used the condensed view and it looks like pretty close of the result I wanted.